# Submit user id and display username?

Tags: php, laravel

I got this form

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="clientId">Client</label>
        <select name="client_id" class="form-control">

            @if(count($client) == 0)
            <option>There are no clients.</option>
            @else
                @foreach($client as $client)
                    <option value="{{$client->client_id}}">{{$client->client_name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            @endif

        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

Which sends the data to this controller

```
public function store(Request $r)
    {

        $validatedData = $r->validate([
            'proj_title' => 'required|max:100',
            'client_id' => 'required',
            'proj_desc' => 'required',
        ]);


        $currentUserId = Auth::user()->user_id;
        $currentUser = User::find('username')->name;

        $r['created_by'] = $currentUser;

        $project = Project::create($r->all());
        return redirect('/projects')->with('store','');
    }
```

I have done a one-to-many relationship from Client to Project.

My intention is that you submit the client_id, inserts that into the db and then on the index you see the client_name relative to that client_id.

This is my index

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Project Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Client</th>
            <th>Created by</th>
            <th>Created on</th>
            @if (Auth::user()->role=='admin')
            <th>Admin</th>

            @endif
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody class="">
        @foreach ($project as $project)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$project->proj_id}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->proj_title}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->proj_desc}}</td>
            <td>{{$client->client_name}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->created_by}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->created_at}}</td>
```

These are my relations:
Project model:

```
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'proj_id';
    protected $fillable = ['proj_title','proj_desc','client_id','created_by'];

     public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User');
    }

    public function task()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
    }
public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Client');
    }
}
```

Client:

```
class Client extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'client_id';

    protected $fillable= ['client_name','client_id'];

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Project','proj_id');
    }
}
```

As I have it right now I get "Property [client_name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: D:\Programas\xampp\htdocs\test5\resources\views\projects\index.blade.php)"

Relations are still a bit confusing to me so sorry if this is a very noob question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are your relationships between client and project? Edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Added the models

Comment: Project has no relation to client.

Comment: oof I really missed that

Comment: The question stills the same tho

Comment: Well once your project has a client relationship then you can `$project->client->client_name`

Comment: That gives me this error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'clients.project_proj_id' in 'where clause'"

Answer (score 0):

Client relation:

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
}
```

Project relation:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Project','proj_id');
}
```

And to get client name simply use `$project->client->client_name`, btw. use plural, learn writing code correctly...